# Redefine a derived class' variable

Tags: c++, inheritance

Is the following valid? Or how can I get something close to this.

```
template<class T_> class Template {
   //something
};

class Parent {
public:
   Template<Parent> variable;

   Parent() : variable(this) { }
};

class Derived : public Parent {
public:
   Template<Derived> variable;

   Derived() : Parent() { }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's technically "valid" in that your compiler has to accept it (it *may* warn you, and IMHO it **should**), but it doesn't do what you think it does: Derived's `variable` is separate from `Parent`'s, and is *not* getting explicitly initialized (so it uses the default ctor for `Template<>`).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a variable with the same name in a base and derived class you don't need templates.

Just define them and from derived access ->variable and ->Base::variable. Those are 2 different variables.

Comment: Therefore, base calling variable will get its own version.

Answer (score 1):

Few minor types.
But the main problem was that Parent was using a constructor on Template that did not exist.

```
template<class T>
class Template
{
    public:
        Template()      {}  // Used in Derived
        Template(T* t)  {}  // Used in Parent
};

class Parent
{
    public:
       Template<Parent> variable;

        Parent() : variable(this)   {}
};

class Derived : public Parent
{
    public:
       Template<Derived> variable;

       Derived() : Parent()         {}
};
```

I am curious what you are trying to achieve though.
Is this some variation of the "Curiously Reoccurring Template" Pattern or something?

Comment: This is a similar scheme to my event system. Template=EventChain. Event declarations should be void handler(T_ &caller, .....). Parent triggers variable (ClickEvent) event. So by somehow declaring ClickEvent in the Derived class I was hoping to allow user to define handler(Derived &) instead of handler(Parent &).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't get something close to this, because such a redefinition of a public variable violates [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) - your `Derived` becomes more restrictive than `Parent`, and cannot be substituted in its place, and therefore it shouldn't be in a superclass/subclass relation.

Furthermore, if it would allow you to redefine a field in a sense of actually reusing the same memory location somehow, then it would break the type system as well: all methods in `Parent` expect `variable` to be of type `Template<Parent>`; if it actually be an instance of `Template<Derived>`, there is no guarantee that `Template<T>` is covariant in `T`.